# How to minimize distance(height) between two alpaca components

Tags: text, alpacajs

I am trying to keep two text boxes with no distance between them and one below another using alpaca. its my design requirement.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. Actually I wanted to do this for slider to customize. But JQuery UI slider worked after changing the version of the library file.